# Leaflet.Geodesic.js line not drawn

Tags: leaflet, geodesic

I am trying to use Leaflet.Geodesic.js geodesic to draw a geodesic line between two points, but I don't see any line at all.

Based on the Leaflet.Geodesic.js example script, this is what I have tried...

```
var Geodesic = L.geodesic([[52.5, 13.35, 33.82, -118.38]], {
opacity: 1,
color: 'red',
steps: 50
}).addTo(map);
```

Can anyone help me see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried the exact same example from the docs that you built upon?

Comment: Yes I have but for some reason it doesn't work for me, I can add Polylines but not Geodesic lines.

Comment: I have now solved this by directly linking to the Leaflet.Geodesic.js script on the authors demo site. Any attempt to use a locally stored copy fails. Must be finger trouble my end but for the life of me I cant see any error. Anyway this issue is now closed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Geodesic = L.geodesic([[[52.5, 13.35], [33.82, -118.38]]], {
  opacity: 1,
  color: 'red',
  steps: 50
}).addTo(map);
```

> Instantiates a polyline object given an array `[point_1, point_2, point_3]` of geographical points, which is basically an array of arrays of LatLng points `[[lat1, lng1], [lat2, lng2], [lat3, lng3]]`.

---

**References:**

- [Leaflet's Polyline](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#polyline)
- [Leaflet's Geodesic](https://github.com/henrythasler/Leaflet.Geodesic#creationesic)
- [LeafletJS - Vector Layers](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/leafletjs/leafletjs_vector_layers.htm)